# Script for exporting to JPEG from Flash CS6?

Tags: cs6, adobe-flash, actionscript

Is there a Script for exporting `.jpg` files from **Flash CS6**?

Another possible solution would be to add an extra button to Export directly to overjump by going to something like `File > Export > Export Image` and saving to a location.

Comment: What about assigning a shortcut key to Export Image dialog box?

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>File > Publish settings... > JPEG IMAGE ( Quality to 100 )</kbd>

Then select `Publish`

I hope this will help you out.